# Portainer: Host Job with docker prune doesnt work

Tags: docker, portainer

I have the latest portainer running to manage my images and containers in docker.

For cleaning up I want to have the command "docker images prune" to run daily.

For this I want to use Portainer host jobs, like it is shown [here](https://github.com/portainer/portainer/issues/3490#issuecomment-573954035).

I did extaclty the same setting, same commands, but in my portinaer there is just 1 "created" conntainer of the ubuntu image and nothing happens.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing docker image from `ubuntu:latest` to `ubuntu:18.04` fixed this issue for me